# Retrieve get response with Android

Tags: java, android, servlets, get, response

I have an app android that in an AsyncTask make 2 get request to a servlet.
I want to retrieve a String that contains a simple response.
This is my AsyncTask:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;
        String responseStr = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));


            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);


                try {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                    URI getURL = new URI("http://192.168.1.101:8080/MusaServlet?collection="+collection+"&name="+filename);
                    Log.i("QUERY",getURL.getQuery());
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                                Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                            }
                    responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(responseGet.getEntity());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseStr;

    }
```

Instead the servlet code is:

```
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("HELLO STUPID APP!");
```

However the dialog showed by app is empty! No words!
What's the problem guys?

Thank's

Comment: are you getting `Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));` in logcat ?

Comment: How can I check in the logcat?

Comment: use DDMS or debug `uploadFile` method by adding break point

Comment: I have published my logcat in a answer. Look there.
No GET RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

At first check your GET request status code as

```
responseGet.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

If is giving number 200 then **GET** is successfull.
Now if is 200 then you will get the response what you have sent by following code

```
 HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
```

and then

```
 String result;
 if(resEntityGet !=null ){
     result=   EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
 }
```

Now the most important thing is once you perform `responseGet.getEntity()` the data of GET response will be passed to the variable.. you assign.. and later on calling `responseGet.getEntity()` will always return empty...

That may be the reason you are getting empty response in your dialog

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Ok I have modified my code and playing with logcat I'm sure that the responseCode is not 200.
What is the problem now?  -.-"